# I need help with an IF-AND formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need help in creating a formula (in Google Sheets) which concatenates three cells of data together in a specified order indicated by two dropdown boxes. Below is a picture of my test spreadsheet.

[image]

I would like assistance in writing a formula in the result cell which has the following results:

Auxiliary-Root-Affix IF B1="Pre-verb" AND B2="Suffix"

Auxiliary-Affix-Root IF B1="Pre-verb" AND B2="Prefix"

Root-Affix-Auxiliary IF B1="Post-verb" AND B2="Suffix"

Affix-Root-Auxiliary IF B1="Post-verb" AND B2="Prefix"

I'm a conlanger if you couldn't tell :P .

Comment: Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168370/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that contains your manually entered desired results in a couple of sample cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake because `case2` and `case4` are equal:

**case2**: IF(B1=`"Post-verb" AND B2="Prefix"` then

**case4**: IF(B1=`"Post-verb" AND B2="Prefix"` then

BTW: try this formula:

```
=Ifs(
    B1 & B2="Pre-verb"&"Prefix", B3 & B4 & B5,
    B1 & B2="Post-verb"&"Prefix",B4 & B5 & B3,
    B1 & B2="Pre-verb"&"Suffix", B3 & B5 & B4,
    B1 & B2="Post-verb"&"Suffix",B5 & B4 & B3
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional statement such as `ifs()` or `switch()`, like this:

```
=switch( B1 & B2, 
  "Pre-verb" & "prefix", B3 & B4 & B5, 
  "Post-verb" & "prefix", B4 & B5 & B3, 
  "Pre-verb" & "suffix", B3 & B5 & B4, 
  "Post-verb" & "suffix", B5 & B4 & B3, 
  "(please choose both locations)"
)
```